# How to Repeat a shape and fill box in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have a rectangular box and would like to put a circle or any other shape inside it and repeat it so that the shape fills the box. How can this be done in Visio?

Update: Not through programming. I'm just checking if there is such feature in MS Visio.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean repeat the circle shape until the rectangle is filled even if it is a non-integer repeat count then no. I assume you don't want the circle to overflow the rectangle.